# regex pattern highlight n sequence string words inside double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

This my script to Highlight a specific word from text string my only problem is when I want to highlight three sequence words it just the 1st word highlighted then 2nd still without highlight then the third one it is highlighted

The `*` its a truncation and works well

the `?` to highlight words+ n characters

This an Example to highlight n sequence words.
my problem here I want to highlight the words that inside `""` 
when I have double quotes highlights the words that inside quotes.

"reference is" need to be highlighted not separated words

exp: reference is good is test1 test2  (here highlight only `reference is` )

```js
var row = {
  "Abstract": "I have a reference server for reference and just a server here." 
};

//here i need to highlight "reference is" to serve test* (n sequnence words)

var wordsToHighlight = '"reference is" to ser?? test*';
var result = row["Abstract"];

wordsToHighlight.split(" ").forEach(function (word) {
  word = word.replace(/\*/g, '\\S*').replace(/\?/g, '.').replace(/\"/g, '.');
  result = result.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)(' + word + ')(?=\\s|$)', "gi"),'$1<span style="background-color:yellow;">$2</span>');
});
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: You should explain what you are after. It seems to me you have not really tried to solve the current issue. How should the highlighter parse `var wordsToHighlight = '"reference is" to ser?? test*'`?

Comment: when i have double quotes  highlight the words that inside it

Comment: `to serve` `test` `testing` `tests` need to be highlighted also plus `reference is`

Comment: it works like charm!! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the original `wordsToHighlight` string with

```
.split(/"([^"]+)"|\s+/).filter(Boolean)
```

It will split the string with double quotes substrings while pushing the substring between double quotes into the resulting array (`String#split` always pushes the captured substrings into the resulting array), and with 1+ whitespaces and `.filter(Boolean)` will remove empty items that may result during the split operation.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aYsUTC/1).

JS demo:

```js
var row = {
  "Abstract": "This reference is to serve test as a useful reference for testing whether the styling of reference works or not. Adtest all occurrences of 'reference' should be given a color of red tests" 
};

//here i need to highlight "reference is" to serve test* (n sequnence words)

var wordsToHighlight = '"reference is" to ser?? test*';
var result = row["Abstract"];

wordsToHighlight.split(/"([^"]+)"|\s+/).filter(Boolean).forEach(function (word) {
  word = word.replace(/\*/g, '\\S*').replace(/\?/g, '.').replace(/\"/g, '.');
  result = result.replace(new RegExp('(\\s|^)(' + word + ')(?=\\s|$)', "gi"),'$1<span style="background-color:yellow;">$2</span>');
});
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I have another example if I have `wordsToHighlight = "reference, server" `mean highlight just `reference` `server`

Comment: @MokiNex Replace `\s+` with `[\s,]+`.

Comment: your mehtode works well just i want to add this condition if i have `"word1 , word2"` highlight `word1 word2` exp `wordsToHighlight = "reference, server"` mean highlight just `reference server`

Comment: @MokiNex I doubt I understand you. If you have `wordsToHighlight = "reference, server"`, do you mean you want to highlight a sequence of these two words? See https://jsfiddle.net/6gd8vw3n/6/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6gd8vw3n/9/ this is my example as an input to highlight words

Comment: @MokiNex I am really guessing now, try https://jsfiddle.net/6gd8vw3n/16/

Comment: the word `server` needs to be highlighted in all text when i have `"word1,word2"` word 1 and word2 need to be highlighted in all text

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your new requirements.